# ftp through ssh tunnel

Tags: redirect, ssh, ftp, portforwarding, tunneling

I have a machine running an ftp server and I'd like to access it from a machine located on another network behind a router only authorizing port 80.

I was thinking of a ssh tunnel like:

```
ssh -L local_port:${ftphost}:20 user@{sshhost}
```

Where ${sshhost} is another machine that have access to the ftp server ${ftphost}.

${sshhost} is reachable from my host while ${ftphost} is only reachable from ${sshhost} not mine.

Would that be the best solution ?

Comment: @rzr: there is no need to add tags for the sake of filling the tag list -- edits should only be made where they improve the context of the question significantly.

Answer (score 8):

The O'Reilly Book "*SSH, The Secure Shell: The Definitive Guide*" contains a whole chapter about  [FTP Forwarding](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch11_02.htm).
I think that should answer all of your questions.